# What is wrong with my angular factory to add item on the list?

Tags: angularjs

As a practice to make simple to-do list with angular, I had a problem in adding item method.

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in thingsTodo">{{todo}}</li>
    <li><input ng-model="addMe">
        <button ng-click="addItem()">add</button></li>
</ul>
</body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
                     .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, service){

                      $scope.thingsTodo = service.thingsTodo();
                      $scope.addItem = service.addItem($scope.addMe);

     });

     app.factory('service', function(){

         var list = ["grocery shopping", "programming", "playing guitar"];

         return{

            thingsTodo :  function (){      
                 return list;
             },

            addItem : function(input){
                 list.push(input);
                 return list;
            }
         };
      });

</script>
```

When "add" button is clicked, the item typed in should be added. But even before add button clicked, blank is still added.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You have specified `addItem` to be a function in your html, but it is not a function in your controller. Change it to:

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    service.addItem($scope.addMe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.addItem = service.addItem($scope.addMe);`

This line executes the function immediately, and the result is stored in `$scope.addItem`. So `$scope.addItem` is not a function (except the return result is a function), and you can't invoke it later by using `$scope.addItem()`

What you actually need is the `.bind` function from javascript.

`$scope.addItem = service.addItem.bind(null, $scope.addMe)`

This is almost equivalent to

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
  service.addItem($scope.addMe);
}
```

which is mentioned in another answer.